# Jasper bar chart : Months in a year

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I have a table with values and months I would like the category section of my bar chart to contain the months with values and also show the months without values in other words, If January has a value then show the bar if not then just show the month name but with no bar. My bar chart is only showing the months with values. Am new to jasper charts your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Please check my source script:

```
<categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Low Severity"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{mth}.intValue() == 1 ?
    "January" :
    $F{mth}.intValue() == 2 ?
    "February" :
    $F{mth} == 3 ?
    "March" :
    $F{mth} == 4 ?
    "April" :
    $F{mth} == 5 ?
    "May":
    $F{mth} == 6 ?
    "June" :
    $F{mth} == 7 ?
    "July":
 $F{mth} == 8 ?
    "August":
 $F{mth} == 9 ?
    "September":
 $F{mth} == 10 ?
    "October":
 $F{mth} == 11 ?
    "November":
 $F{mth} == 12 ?
    "December":""]]></categoryExpression>
```

Comment: Can you post the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the JRXML, I think the problem is you simply don't have any data for January.  As a results, no data even exists with the $F{mth} value of "1"